# How to make a connection with MySQL in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am new to NodeJS application development.

My requirement is to store my registration form data in a MySQL database.

Before that, I want to know how to establish the connection with a MySQL database.
After that, store the form data.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You're describing a fairly common task, there are plenty of resources on the internet for that (this site included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I present to you NPM and the world of requiring packages. ;)

NPM stands for [Node Package Manager](https://www.npmjs.com). It is where we can add public or private packages that extends Node functionalities.

Take a look at the [MySQLpackage for NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) .

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); 
var connection = mysql.createConnection(
  {   
    host     : 'localhost',   
    user     : 'me',  
    password : 'secret',   
    database : 'my_db' 
  });   

  connection.connect();  

  connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', 
    function(err, rows, fields) {   if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution); 
    });   

  connection.end();
```

With this, you can simply connect to your DB.